# MySQL Trigger: UPDATE parent row AFTER DELETE in child row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to update the value of the parent table, when a child row is deleted.

**Parent table:** (*answers*)

- id_answer
- answer
- **votes** (contains total of votes)

**Children table:** (*answers_votes*)

- id_vote
- id_answer
- id_user
- date_insert
- ip

Each time a child row is deleted, the value of **votes** in the parent table must be decreased by 1.

This is my current sentence to create the trigger, but something is wrong with the UPDATE line, perhaps the *votes-1*? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_votes BEFORE DELETE on answers_votes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE answers SET answers.votes = (answers.votes-1) WHERE answers.id_answer = OLD.id_answer;
END
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this ? `DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_votes BEFORE DELETE ON answers_votes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE answers SET answers.votes = (answers.votes -1 ) WHERE answers.id_answer = OLD.id_answer;
END$$ DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Also, no delimiter was present and it was terminating at `update` line, so I added `$$` as delimiter.

Comment: @harshavmb That worked! If you post your solution I can select it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I suspect `;` is the problem here. I've added `$$` as the `DELIMITER` so that mysql client will not misinterpret `;`.

Your modified trigger will be :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_votes
BEFORE DELETE ON answers_votes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE answers SET answers.votes = (answers.votes -1 ) WHERE answers.id_answer = OLD.id_answer;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Note, it is `DELIMITER ;` not `DELIMITER;`

Hope this helps!